# Multiple spaces in a file name passed to a bash script

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a script named script1, and I want to pass to it one file named `file    in 1` (with 4 spaces between "file and "in")

So, I want to be able to pass this file name to the script without using "":

```
./script1 file    in 1
```

instead of:

```
./script1 "file    in 1"
```

I tried to use "$*" in the script to receive the file name correctly, but what the script receives is: `file in 1` (the spaces are omitted)

Is there a way to do that in bash?

Comment: Try using `./script1 file\ in\ 1`...

Comment: Why would you not want to use quotes? You have to escape the spaces *somehow* if they are really part of the file name, and using quotes is far simpler than escaping each space initially, especially if you really have 4 spaces in a row: `./script "file˽˽˽˽in˽1"` instead of `./script file\˽\˽\˽\˽in\˽1`.

Comment: I agree that it's not natural, but It's something that me and my friends from school try to overcome, because we think that our teacher will test this feature in our assignment.

Comment: Test what feature? Your script isn't *supposed* to deal with the user's failure to properly quote its arguments. It can't magically reconstruct a file name that isn't passed correctly in the first place.

Comment: I don't know how they will test the script we wrote, but we think that the input ./script file####in#1 is possible (# is space)

Comment: If you are properly quoting `"$1"` in your script, you are doing it right. It's the caller's responsibility to make sure a single argument with 4 consecutive spaces is passed, not yours.

Comment: `$@` instead of `$*` might help.

Comment: @LjmDullaart No, it won't. There is nothing the script can do to distinguish between `./script file˽˽˽˽in˽1` and `script file˽in˽1`. They are two identical invocations.

Comment: yes, sorry. The spaces are handled in the calling shell, not in the script. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can or should do. Suppose your script is (correctly) written as

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1"
```

If your instructor expects your script to handle

```
./script file    in 1
```

and

```
./script "file    in 1"
```

identically, your instructor is profoundly mistaken about how the shell works.

Answer (score -1):

The command:

```
./script file    in 1
```

will execute `./scrip` with three distinct input files: `file`, `in`, and `1`. If you want `./scrip` to read `file    in 1` as a single file but don't want to use quotes in the call, then you have some options:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Not ideal, as it also matches any number of characters 
# between "file", "in" and "1": file--in--1
cat "$(ls $1*$2*$3)"                  

# Better but also matches single (or any number) of spaces: file in 1
cat "$(ls $1*$2*$3 | grep "$1 *$2 *$3")"

# Will only match: file    in 1
cat "$(ls $1*$2*$3 | grep -E "$1 {4}$2 {1}$3")"
```

Comment: but that will also match `fileXinY1` -- this kind of approach is really not a road that you want to travel.